# Why NullPointerException is not thrown in the following Java Stream filter method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The second object of `Blankie` has a color value of null, when it passes through the stream pipeline it checks equals() on a null but surprisingly NullPointerException is not thrown. Why is it like this?

package myth;

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Blankie {
    String color = null;

    boolean isPink() {
        return "pink".equals(color);
    }
}

public class PreSchool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blankie b1 = new Blankie();
        Blankie b2 = new Blankie();
        b1.color = "pink";
        // String a1 = null;
        // System.out.println(a1.equals("ad"));
        Stream.of(b1, b2).peek(a -> {
            System.out.print(a.color);
        }).filter(Blankie::isPink).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats beacause you are doing "pink".equals(color) and not color.equals("pink").

Comment: @melli-182 Thanks. This is the mistake I made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason a `NullPointerException` would be thrown. The `equals()` method of `String` will accept an argument of `null` and return `false`. For two string values `s1` and `s2`, the expression `s1.equals(s2)` will only throw a `NullPointerException` if `s1` is `null`. In your code, `s1` is the string constant `"pink"`.

Answer (score 2):

`something.equals(null)` is just `false`.

look at java.lang.String#equals implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {   // null is NOT instance of String 
        ...
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you referencing `Object.equals`? Shouldn't it be `String.equals` ?

Comment: Thank you, It's a little misspelling here. String.equals starts with the same pice of code. I'll edit the answer immediately. Actually, I was allready in "edit mode" while receiving your commet :)

Comment: ok, but note that this code snippet is not a relevant test to reason about what happens when the anObject argument is null

Comment: sorry, another typo. now should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
color.equals("pink");
```

it will throw a NPE.

But

***"pink"*** is a ***String*** and

```
"pink".equals(color);
```

is the same as

```
"pink".equals(null);
```

If you are trying to avoid NPE, its a good idea to do A.equals(B) and always choose your A object as the one that you know its not ***null***, like a ***Constant*** or ***Enum***.

Answer (score 0):

NPE is thrown when a property is accessed or method is called on Null reference and that is done by JVM and not the code. There are some instances of implementations that I have seen for some methods that throw NPE if argument is Null but that is wrong implementation, In those cases IllegalArgumentException makes much more sense.

In case of String equals method, following things are done:

1. Check if both references are Same
2. Check if passed argument is of type String if so:

   a.   Get the char arrays from both string and compare each character one by one from left to right. If everything goes fine return true
3. Otherwise return false

So, point is code should not throw NPEs, they make implementation more bug prone. There are much better ways to do that.

Comment: Just want to give Design perspective with this answer..otherwise other answers pretty much answer the question asked..